# RMSProp in TF VS Pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

In Pytorch's RMSProp implementation we are given the parameter `alpha` which according to the documentation:

`alpha (float, optional) – smoothing constant (default: 0.99)`

On the other hand, TF's implementation has the parameter `rho` (Formally named `decay`):

`rho    Discounting factor for the history/coming gradient. Defaults to 0.9.`

Are those parameters the same with different names or are they different?
I couldn't find any information regarding the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare the source code of PyTorch ([here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/rmsprop.py#L23)) and that of Tensorflow ([on a forked build](https://github.com/NLPatVCU/Sentiment-Classification/blob/master/keras_test/keras_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/gen_training_ops.py#L901)), you will see that `alpha` and `rho` are indeed the same.

Although, as opposed to Tensorflow, PyTorch [is clear](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.RMSprop.html) about the underlying logic for its module:

[image]